# Black screen when booting into Mac , external monitor works

Tags: macbook-pro, display, bootcamp, windows, startup

I've **Macbook Pro (Reina Mid 2016)** , Graphics: **Iris Pro** .

I tried to install windows 10 using Boot Camp , it seemed to work. I was able to boot into windows.It worked for about 30-40 minutes and suddenly black screen. I figured it's graphics driver for windows failing. I did hard reboot and was able to boot again. After a while resolution changed and got notification graphics driver failed. I got black screen rebooted couple of times and same thing happened and after a point never recovered. I thought , it's corrupted graphics driver so **uninstalled Bootcamp windows** altogether. Nothing , still black screen tried following to no avail.

1) Reset PRAM , NVRAM
2) Reset SMC
3) Drained battery and reset again
4) **Able to see , on external monitor** so not an issue with setup.
5) **Can't see backlight , Apple logo at back not lighting up**. Nothing on screen , not even Apple logo loading same can be seen on external monitor though.

Please , let me know if something can be done. I would greatly appreciate that !

Answer (score 1):

I know this may sound bizarre but have you checked your native screens settings? Such as brightness controls etc?
If they are all correct, have you tried running the MBP with power plugged in and the battery removed?
Otherwise, have you tried re-seating the ribbon connector for the screen? You can find the guide here: https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+17-Inch+Unibody+Display+Replacement/3438 
However, if this is a mid 2016 model, then I wouldn't hesitate to go the warranty route with apple and opening it up could invalidate your warranty.

Comment: Oh ! It is not under warranty. I did check screen setting , full brightness. I ran a diagnostic and , it says there might be problem with display VFD002.   I'm not sure , if it'd help to tinker around , if diagnostic detects as hardware issue.

Comment: I'm confused as to how it could NOT be under warranty? It's a mid 2016 and  impossible for you have had it for more then a year which is the standard warranty. VFD002 is the generic error for a screen problem so it's not much help. What other error messages do you get? You may need to completely format the main drive and install OSX fresh. If that doesn;t solve it then you have a hardware fault. If so, get it fixed under warranty but if there's none,, then I would open it, remove screen, clean connectors, reseat, put back together. Do the same for the video card.

Comment: Oops , my bad there. It says , it is mid - 2016 but that must be because of MacOs Sierra. It must be mid 2015 , I suppose. How else can this be checked ? About mac shows mid - 2016. I heard mid - 2013 models had extended warranty for video issues.

Comment: Correct, there was a fault with the video cards and even screen on certain models but it was corrected later on so you'd really have to contact apple or go to an apple store to check if yours has the extension. Bear in mind the black screen of death failure has plagued certain MPB's and in some cases, you're on your own as apple didn't officially recognize the problems. You may well have to get a new screen but again, if you're sure it's out of warranty, do the ifixit guide to remove the screen & video card, properly clean the connectors & reassemble. It could just be a loose connector..

Comment: Thanks , it is out of warranty and likely logic board or screen issue as you pointed out.I went to service centre and they said it's one of those issues , but gave me option to extend warranty for 2 years ; then it'd be fixed under warranty. It's been about 3 months since my warranty expired.I think it'd be wise to extend warranty , I'm going to do just that.

Comment: Yeah, it's worth it to do that - the extended warranty option is a fraction of what the parts and labor will cost you and if anything else goes wrong in the next two years, you're still covered. Congrats and hope you get it all fixed!